# How can I send a node (any) to an xsl:function?

Tags: xml, xslt

Can I send a node to an XSLT function? For example:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <author>a1</author>
    <price>10</price>
    <year>2009</year>
  </book>
  <!-- ... -->
</books>
```

Can I send the `<book>` element to a function - within that function I want to process the nodes under book (`<author>`, `<price>` or `<year>`)

Can I create a xsl:function as below ?

```
 <xsl:function name="util:checkNode" as="xs:boolean">
      <!-- I would like to know xml schema data type for the param -->
       <xsl:param name="nodeP" as="****"/>
  </xsl:function


          If yes, what xsl schema type to the param ?
```

It looks like i created lot of confusion to every one by saying function instead of xsl:function ---- :(

Comment: Are you asking for people to write actual code for you? This won't work very well, I'm afraid...

Comment: Given the wording of the question ("function", etc.) and desire to simply process the node, i think @unknown is pretty new to xslt. And some sample code using books/book might help, particularly for other xslt newbies finding this question in a search.

Comment: I am looking for a XSLT function, which accepts a node (basically any node it may be) as a param to the XSLT function ? If yes can i have the syntax for the XSLT function ?

Comment: Why did you paste your original question as a comment in each answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is, yes. You **can** send a node to an XSLT function.

If you are wondering what to use for the value of the as="" attribute, you have several choices.  If you want to be very lax and accept just about anything, use **as="item()*"**.

[From David Pawson's site](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/exampler2.html#istar):

> item()* .. sort of nodeset? W3C
>
> Yes, I agree it looks pretty
>   meaningless doesn't it. However. As of
>   CR, its pretty essential, especially
>   if you want to use types. And want to
>   generate, say, a nodeset.. sorry
>   sequence, in a variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="a"
 select="(//h3)[position() < 3]"
 as="item()*"/>
```

> This creates a variable you can hack
>   into using xpath quite readily. I.e.
>   remember item()*.
>
> types ... a few examples. W3C
>
> From an explanatory email from Mike
>   Kay, thanks Mike. Examples:
>
> `<xsl:param name="x" as="item()"/>`
>
> the parameter value can be any item
>   (i.e. a node or atomic value). But it
>   must be a single item.
>
> `<xsl:param name="x" as="item()?"/>`
>
> the parameter can be a single item or
>   an empty sequence
>
> `<xsl:param name="x" as="item()+"/>`
>
> the parameter must be a sequence of
>   one or more items - an empty sequence
>   is not allowed
>
> `<xsl:param name="x" as="item()*"/>`
>
> the parameter can be any sequence of
>   zero or more items - this places no
>   constraints on its value.
>
> `<xsl:param name="x" as="node()*"/>`
>
> the parameter can be any sequence of
>   zero or more nodes
>
> `<xsl:param name="x" as="xs:atomicValue*"/>`
>
> the parameter can be any sequence of
>   zero or more atomic values (e.g.
>   integers, strings, or booleans).
>
> item()* is the most general type
>   possible, it matches everything, like
>   "Object" in Java. For that reason, it
>   can usually be omitted. But not
>   always, for example the default type
>   in xsl:variable is not item()* but
>   document-node(), to ensure that
>
> `<xsl:variable name="rtf"><a>thing</a> </xsl:variable>`
>
> continues to behave like XSLT 1.0
>
> Use these to specify parameters,
>   variable types etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of XSLT functions that accept nodes as parameters.  For instance, all of the arguments of `concat` can be nodes, e.g.:

```
concat(myelement, myelement/@myattribute)
```

While this answers precisely the question you asked, I would bet folding money that it's not the question you wanted answered.  But heck, you asked it four times, so here you go.

**Edit**

Actually, attributes aren't nodes; only elements, text, comments, processing instructions, and CDATA sections are nodes.  But the above example still answers the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

XSL does not care what the parameter is. It really treats everything as XML. If text is passed in it is treated as a text node.

Here is an example with a link for further reference.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

```
<xsl:call-template name="TemplateName">
    <xsl:with-param name="ParamName" select="MyNode/MyNode" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="TemplateName">
    <xsl:param name="ParamName" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am looking for a XSLT function, which accepts a node (basically any node it may be) as a param to the XSLT function ? If yes can i have the syntax for the XSLT function ?

Answer (score -1):

To add to the [ChaosPandion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156142/chaospandion) answer you may need to add a [node test](http://vistech.net/~champ/online-docs/books/XML/xslt/appb_02.htm) to your XPath query:

```
<xsl:call-template name="TemplateName">
    <xsl:with-param name="ParamName" select="MyNode/MyNode/node()" />
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="TemplateName">
    <xsl:param name="ParamName" />
</xsl:template>
```

Officially, `node()` is not a function it is a test but can returns a value that is like the `XmlNode.InnerXml` property.

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to mean, but your XPath is semantically different from the one ChaosPandion's answer.

Comment: Looks I am not clear in my question, can i have a function which accepts the node as a parameter ? If yes, can i have a sample code syntax ?

Comment: Pavel, I am aware that .InnerXml is different from .OuterXml---and that /MyNode/node() is different from /MyNode.

Comment: I am looking for a XSLT function, which accepts a node (basically any node it may be) as a param to the XSLT function ? If yes can i have the syntax for the XSLT function ?

Answer (score -1):

In your question:

> Can I send the <book> element to a function - within that function I want to process the nodes under book (<author>,
>   <price> or <year>)

and later comment:

> can i have a function which accepts the node as a parameter?

...you're asking for a function, but what **i think you want is a [`template`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp) for the `book` element**.

Of course, you could do this several ways--in a [`for-each`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_for-each.asp) loop, actually sending the `book` node into a template using [`with-param`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_with-param.asp), etc.--but a simple [`template`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp) should accomplish what you need. Whatever the template matches is the "parameter".

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="books">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    author: <xsl:value-of select="author" />
    price: <xsl:value-of select="price" />
    year: <xsl:value-of select="year" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to do **some further processing** on the sub-elements (author, price, and year), you could look into creating templates for them too. Keep in mind that matching "year" will match **all** year elements, even for those you might have in date of births etc. (In these cases you would probably want to restrict the XPath in the match or just keep the `book/year` processing within the book template.) Say you want to do something extra with `year`. Your book processing might evolve into something like this (where you're now passing each `year` node as parameters into the year template):

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    author: <xsl:value-of select="author" />
    price: <xsl:value-of select="price" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="year" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="year">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="year &lt; '2000'">
         from a prior century: <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         from this century: <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am looking for a XSLT function, which accepts a node (basically any node it may be) as a param to the XSLT function ? If yes can i have the syntax for the XSLT function ?